# WebDriver JavaScriptExecutor not clicking on button

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver with C# and NUnit.
The application under test has a button that Selenium will not identify.  I have tried all the usual locators including various XPath statements, Id, CSSSelector etc.  In all cases, a `NullReferenceException` occurs.

I then tried the following:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor javaScript = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver.Instance;

javaScript.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('listingstep1').click();
```

This also results in the `NullReferenceException`. Other buttons in the application can be clicked without error.
This particular button is as follows:

```
<div class="space-top-4 mdl-layout__canvas-action-hide-sm">
    <a id="listing-step1" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <button class="mdl-button md-min mdl-color--blue mdl-color-text--white mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect" data-       upgraded=",MaterialButton,MaterialRipple">
                    NEXT
            <span class="mdl-button__ripple-container">
                <span class="mdl-ripple"></span>
            </span>
        </button>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't look like valid html to me - you don't normally nest a `<button>` in an `<a>` tag

Comment: The id in HTML is `listing-step1`, but in your C# code is `listingstep1`, It's a really code issue or copy/paste issue when you put code here.

Comment: Elements that cannot be identified don't throw a Null Reference Exception. You've got an issue somewhere else in your code. You should take some time to debug your code and determine more of what is going on. Once you've done that, edit your question and add those details. Add some more code examples of what you've tried. A link to the page would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.id('listing-step1')));
```

Answer (score 0):

To invoke `Click()` on the button with text as **NEXT** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* and you can use the following code block:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//button[@class='mdl-button md-min mdl-color--blue mdl-color-text--white mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect']//span[@class='mdl-button__ripple-container']/span[@class='mdl-ripple']"))).Click();
```

Comment: That is what I normally do but it does not help in this instance - thanks.  I use that method on every other object and it works fine.  I think it may be to do with the fact that the button is nested in the <a> tag.  The developers are going to change it and I will see if that works.

Comment: @MichaelPiraner There are a lot many ways to address the issue you are facing and the steps to be followed are decided as per the observations. If you can update the question with your latest code trials and error stack trace we can work out a solution for sure.